# Twitter-Bootstrap drop down log in closes when text areas are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm designing a website with JQuery for the first time. I am using Twitter-Bootstrap for a dropdown login box and I can't get the JQuery script right to make the box stay open when you click on the text area. I've tried everything and I am familiar with java script. I placed the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"</script>
```

at the top of the header as well as before the closing body bracket, and the following in front of the closing body tag as well...

```
<script>$(function() {
  // Setup drop down menu
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

  // Fix input element click problem
  $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});</script>
```

here is the HTML

```
<div id="top-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <ul id="top-info">
                            <li>Phone: 703-518-4325</li>
                            <li>Email: <a href="mailto:info@urbanare.com">info@urbanare.com</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right" id="top-buttons">
                            <li id="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Log in<strong class="caret"></strong></a></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">

                            <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                            email: <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="email" size="30" />
                            password: <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" size="30" />
                            <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                            <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

                            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
                            </form>
                            </div></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="../register"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the CSS

```
#top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 35px;
  max-height: 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1020;
}

#top-buttons{ 
line-height:10px !important;
}

#top-bar a {
  color: #74777c;
}

#top-bar a:hover,
#top-bar a:focus {
  color: #f58220;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#dashboard-top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 45px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1020;
}

#dashboard-top-bar a {
  color: #74777c;
}

#dashboard-top-bar a:hover,
#dashboard-top-bar a:focus {
  color: #f58220;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#top-info,
#top-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#top-info,
#top-buttons li {
 display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#top-buttons {
  float: right;
}

#top-buttons .divider {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #74777c;
  width: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any jquery to do this. include bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css then
 Try this code. 
Ex:- **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c2hhr1jv/)**

```
<div id="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul id="top-info">
                    <li>Phone: 703-518-4325</li>
                    <li>Email: <a href="mailto:info@urbanare.com">info@urbanare.com</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav pull-right" id="top-buttons">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Log in<strong class="caret"></strong></a></a>
                         <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                            email: <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="email" size="30" />
                            password: <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" size="30" />
                            <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                            <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
                        </form>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="../register"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```